# Force Jenkins to rebuild all branches in MultiBranch Pipeline project

Tags: git, jenkins

I would like Jenkins to rebuild all existing git repository branches after scheduled branch indexing even if there were no changes since last build but right now I can do that only manually.

```
Checking branch MyBranch
Met criteria
No changes detected in MyBranch (still at db2c95ede39116529fec42a5fcdd54f0a2dd93d1)
```

Is there any way to trigger a scheduled build if it detects no changes?

Jenkins 2.7.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need - I wanted a clean and a forced build every weekend.
I used the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), created a new job:

[image: The original Pipeline and the weekly rebuild job]

I scheduled it the way I wanted, and added steps to trigger all the branches in the main job:

[image: The new job manually triggers builds on the main pipeline.]

It is not very flexible, as you have to modify the builds to trigger each time you add a branch to your pipeline; it also defeats the "CI as code" and zero configuration principle; but if that's not something you do everyday, and have a procedure your developpers follow when they change something on Jenkins, you can write it down there and be just fine.